# Determine the end time continuously based on the average duration

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to predict the start / end time of an order's processes in SQL. I have determined the average duration for processes from the past.
The processes run in several parallel rows (RNr) and rows are independent of each other. Each row can have 1-30 processes (PNr) that have different durations. The duration of a process may vary and is known only as an average duration.
After one process is completed, the next automatically starts.
So PNr 1 finish = PNr 2 start.

The start time of the first process in each row is known at the beginning and is the same for each row.
When some processes are completed, the times are known and should be used to calculate the more accurate prediction of upcoming processes.
How can I predict the time when a process will be started or stopped?

I used an large subquery to get this table.

```
RNr PNr Duration_avg_h  Start                 Finish
1   1   1               2019-06-06 16:32:11   2019-06-06 16:33:14
1   2   262             2019-06-06 16:33:14   NULL
1   3   51              NULL                  NULL
1   4   504             NULL                  NULL
1   5   29              NULL                  NULL
2   1   1               2019-06-06 16:32:11   NULL
2   2   124             NULL                  NULL
2   3   45              NULL                  NULL
2   4   89              NULL                  NULL
2   5   19              NULL                  NULL
2   6   1565            NULL                  NULL
2   7   24              NULL                  NULL
```

Now I want to find the values ​​for the prediction.

```
SELECT 
    RNr,
    PNr,
    Duration_avg_h,
    Start,
    Finish,
    Predicted_Start = CASE 
      WHEN Start IS NULL 
      THEN DATEADD(HH,LAG(Duration_avg_h, 1,NULL) OVER (ORDER BY RNr,PNr), LAG(Start, 1,NULL) OVER (ORDER BY RNr,PNr)) 
      ELSE Start END,
    Predicted_Finish = CASE 
      WHEN Finish IS NULL 
      THEN DATEADD(HH,Duration_avg_h,Start) 
      ELSE Finish END,
    SUM(Duration_avg_h) over (PARTITION BY RNr ORDER BY RNr, PNr ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Duration_row_h

FROM (...)
ORDER BY RNr, PNr
```

I tried LAG () but with that I only get the values ​​for the next line. I also came to no conclusion with "ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW".

```
RNr PNr Duration_avg_h  Start                   Finish                  Predicted_Start         Predicted_Finish        Duration_row_h
1   1   1               2019-06-06 16:32:11     2019-06-06 16:33:14     2019-06-06 16:32:11     2019-06-06 16:33:14     1
1   2   262             2019-06-06 16:33:14     NULL                    2019-06-06 16:33:14     2019-06-17 14:33:14     263
1   3   51              NULL                    NULL                    2019-06-17 14:33:14     NULL                    314
1   4   504             NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    818
1   5   29              NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    847
2   1   1               2019-06-06 16:32:11     NULL                    2019-06-06 16:32:11     2019-06-06 17:32:11     1
2   2   124             NULL                    NULL                    2019-06-06 17:32:11     NULL                    125
2   3   45              NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    170
2   4   89              NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    259
2   5   19              NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    278
```

So can somebody help me to fill the columns Predicted_Start and Predicted_Finish ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LAG only works if all your rows have values. For this use case you need to cascade the results from one row to another. One way of doing this is with a self join to get running totals

```
--Sample Data
DECLARE @dataset TABLE
(
    RNr             INT
    ,PNr            INT
    ,Duration_avg_h INT
    ,START          DATETIME
    ,Finish         DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO @dataset
(
    RNr             
    ,PNr            
    ,Duration_avg_h 
    ,START
    ,Finish
)
VALUES
 (1, 1, 1,      '2019-06-06 16:32:11',NULL)
,(1, 2, 262,    NULL,NULL)
,(1, 3, 51,     NULL,NULL)
,(1, 4, 504,    NULL,NULL)
,(1, 5, 29,     NULL,NULL)
,(2, 1, 1,      '2019-06-06 16:32:11', NULL)
,(2, 2, 124,    NULL,NULL)
,(2, 3, 45,     NULL,NULL)
,(2, 4, 89,     NULL,NULL)
,(2, 5, 19,     NULL,NULL)
,(2, 6, 1565,   NULL,NULL)
,(2, 7, 24,     NULL,NULL)
```

```
SELECT 
    d.RNr,
    d.PNr,
    d.Duration_avg_h,
    d.Start,
    d.Finish,
    --SUM() gives us the total time up to and including this step
    --take of the current step and you get the total time of all the previous steps
    --this can give us our start time, or when the previous step ended.
    SUM(running_total.Duration_avg_h) - d.Duration_avg_h  AS running_total_time,
    --MIN() gives us the lowest start time we have pre process.
    MIN(running_total.Start) AS min_start,
    ISNULL(
        d.Start
        ,DATEADD(HH,SUM(running_total.Duration_avg_h),MIN(running_total.Start) )
    ) AS Predicted_Start,
    ISNULL(
        d.Finish
        ,DATEADD(HH,SUM(running_total.Duration_avg_h),MIN(running_total.Start) )
    ) AS Predicted_Finish
FROM @dataset AS d
    LEFT JOIN @dataset AS running_total
        ON d.RNr = running_total.RNr
            AND
            --the running total for all steps.
            running_total.PNr <= d.PNr
GROUP BY
    d.RNr,
    d.PNr,
    d.Duration_avg_h,
    d.Start,
    d.Finish
ORDER BY 
    RNr, 
    PNr
```

This code will not work once you have actual finish times unless you update the Duration_avg_h to be the actual hours taken.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan, thanks for your help.
Your idea of using "`MIN (running_total.Start) AS min_start,`" brought me to the idea of using "`MAX (d.Start) OVER (PARTITION BY RNr)`". And this resulted in the following query:

```
--Sample Data
DECLARE @dataset TABLE
(
    RNr             INT
    ,PNr            INT
    ,Duration_avg_h INT
    ,START          DATETIME
    ,Finish         DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO @dataset
(
    RNr             
    ,PNr            
    ,Duration_avg_h 
    ,START
    ,Finish
)
VALUES
 (1, 1, 1,      '2019-06-06 16:32:11','2019-06-06 16:33:14')
,(1, 2, 262,    '2019-06-06 16:33:14','2019-08-22 17:30:00')
,(1, 3, 51,     '2019-08-22 17:30:00',NULL)
,(1, 4, 504,    NULL,NULL)
,(1, 5, 29,     NULL,NULL)
,(2, 1, 1,      '2019-06-06 16:32:11', NULL)
,(2, 2, 124,    NULL,NULL)
,(2, 3, 45,     NULL,NULL)
,(2, 4, 89,     NULL,NULL)
,(2, 5, 19,     NULL,NULL)
,(2, 6, 1565,   NULL,NULL)
,(2, 7, 24,     NULL,NULL)



SELECT  RNr,
        PNr,
        Duration_avg_h,
        Start,
        Finish,         
        --Start_max,
        --Finish_bit,
        --Duration_row_h,
        CASE WHEN Start IS NOT NULL THEN Start ELSE DATEADD(HH,(Duration_row_h - MAX(Duration_row_h*Finish_bit) OVER (PARTITION BY RNr) - Duration_avg_h), Start_max) END as Predicted_Start,
        CASE WHEN Finish IS NOT NULL THEN Finish ELSE DATEADD(HH,(Duration_row_h - MAX(Duration_row_h*Finish_bit) OVER (PARTITION BY RNr)), Start_max) END as Predicted_Finish

FROM ( SELECT 
            RNr,
            PNr,
            Duration_avg_h,
            --Convert to a short DATETIME format
            CONVERT(DATETIME2(0),Start) as Start, 
            CONVERT(DATETIME2(0),Finish) as Finish,
            --Get MAX start time for each row
            Start_max = MAX (CONVERT(DATETIME2(0),d.Start)) OVER (PARTITION BY RNr),
            --If process is finished then 1
            Finish_bit = (CASE WHEN d.Finish IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END),
            --continuously count the Duration of all processes in the row
            SUM(Duration_avg_h) over (PARTITION BY RNr ORDER BY RNr, PNr ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Duration_row_h

        FROM @dataset AS d
    ) AS e

ORDER BY 
    RNr, 
    PNr
```

This query takes into account changes in start and stop times. And calculated by that, the prediction for the upcoming processes.

```
RNr PNr Duration_avg_h  Start                Finish                 Predicted_Start       Predicted_Finish
1   1   1               2019-06-06 16:32:11  2019-06-06 16:33:14    2019-06-06 16:32:11   2019-06-06 16:33:14
1   2   262             2019-06-06 16:33:14  2019-08-22 17:30:00    2019-06-06 16:33:14   2019-08-22 17:30:00
1   3   51              2019-08-22 17:30:00  NULL                   2019-08-22 17:30:00   2019-08-24 20:30:00
1   4   504             NULL                 NULL                   2019-08-24 20:30:00   2019-09-14 20:30:00
1   5   29              NULL                 NULL                   2019-09-14 20:30:00   2019-09-16 01:30:00
2   1   1               2019-06-06 16:32:11  NULL                   2019-06-06 16:32:11   2019-06-06 17:32:11
2   2   124             NULL                 NULL                   2019-06-06 17:32:11   2019-06-11 21:32:11
2   3   45              NULL                 NULL                   2019-06-11 21:32:11   2019-06-13 18:32:11
2   4   89              NULL                 NULL                   2019-06-13 18:32:11   2019-06-17 11:32:11
2   5   19              NULL                 NULL                   2019-06-17 11:32:11   2019-06-18 06:32:11
2   6   1565            NULL                 NULL                   2019-06-18 06:32:11   2019-08-22 11:32:11
2   7   24              NULL                 NULL                   2019-08-22 11:32:11   2019-08-23 11:32:11
```

I think this way is still complicated. Does anyone know maybe a simpler query?

Comment: glad I could be of some help